# Minimum angular speed of Earth for a body to escape its gravity

Tags: newtonian-gravity, centripetal-force

At what angular speed must the Earth rotate for a body to just fly off the surface at the equator?

Comment: What have you thought about so far? Any ideas? (also, you ask two different questions in your title and the body of the text - please clarify :) )

Comment: So we are trying to find the speed at which Earth would have to rotate for the gravitational force to be insufficient to provide the necessary centripetal acceleration. mg-N < mw^2r

Comment: I am not sure what your N is, but I think apart from that your equations are reasonable. You might want to account for the fact that $g$ is already corrected if I remember correctly, but the error in that should be very small.

Answer (score 1):

$$g=\omega^2r$$
$$\omega=\sqrt{9.81/6.4\times10^6}= 1.24\times 10^{-3}$$

The Earth rotates $7.27\times 10^{−5}\:\mathrm{rads^{−1}}$ roughly 17 times slower than the minimum speed to fly off the Earth.

Comment: Please explain your symbols.

Comment: I wonder if $\omega$ rather than $w$ was intended. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

To escape the gravity of earth from its surface, a body has to have at a minimum the known escape speed ve=11.2km/s in any direction away from the surface. The escape speed derives from the kinetic energy that is equal to the (negative) gravitational potential energy of the body at the surface of the earth according to Newton's gravitational law. Therefore, the angular velocity  of the rotation of earth at the equator to achieve this is given by =ve/r, where r= 6378 km is the earth radius at the equator. This yields an angular escape velocity at the equator of  =11.2kms^-1/6378km=1.80·10^-3s^-1. For comparison, the angular velocity of the earth's natural rotation is 7.27·10^-5s-1. Thus the earth's rotation would have to speed up by a factor of 24.8 to let bodies at the equator escape the gravity of earth. This corresponds to reducing the day to 58.2 minutes.

Comment: Question doesn't refer to speed required to be thrown into deep space but for orbit at sea level.

Comment: @gregsan - How do you come to this conclusion? The title says "to escape its gravity". This requires the "escape velocity."

Comment: The ingeneous person who downvoted this answer seems not to have understood the title of the question!

Comment: Bear in mind that if the Earth really did spin that fast, it couldn't hold itself together.  Also, long before it would reach that speed, its equator would bulge out significantly.  The maximum bulge is about 50% larger than now, so that would make a better estimate of the breakup speed of the Earth.  But yes, that's just to get into orbit.  It might be a homework question that doesn't care about any of that.

Comment: @Ken G - You are, of course, right. But such questions usually assume very simplified conditions.